# How to Extract Domain Name from URL using PHP

Tags: php, html, url

I want to know how to extract domain name from url

I have data in a HTML file:

```
<a href='http://google.com.site.com'>google.com</a><br /><a href='http://youtube.com.site.com'>youtube.com</a><br />
```

I can get complete hyperlinks through

```
 preg_match_all ("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+".
                    "(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/",
                    $var, &$matches);

    $matches = $matches[1];
    $list = array();
sort($matches);
```

But I want to extract `google.com`  and `youtube.com`, which is between `<a> and </a>` tags. 
 So how do I do extract `google.com` and `youtube.com`?

Comment: all questions are accepted .... sorry i was unaware about that feature ... but from now i will accept answers

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to just match the link text, this regex works.

```
>(.*?)</a>
```

If you want to parse the actual URL, you could try and ignore everything after some accepted strings such as "com", "net" and "org". This can get quite tricky thought. Do you want to match the host name or what?

As for your example "youtube.com.site.com" please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Domain_name_syntax

If you have an easy access to the URL, check also PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

---

Update. Here's a regex to match URL after `href=` followed by a single or double quote. After this it should be easy to use `parse_url()`

```
<a href=['|"](.*?)?['|"]>
```

---

Update2. Whitespace is the problem. I wasn't able to do a elegant solution but this one takes care of `<br />`s. I'm pretty sure there's more efficient solution. I'll be back if I find one.

```
$s = '<a href='http://google.com.site.com'>google.com</a><br /><a href='http://youtube.com.site.com'>youtube.com</a><br /><a href='http://youtube.com.site.com'>extratube.com</a>';

$pattern = '#>(.*?)</a>(<br />)*#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @user114500 Check if my updated answer works. In the array of arrays, the second array outputs the text between the ´a´ tags. At least works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i write my own regex after passing through alot of trouble

```
<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

this works